# Solve $u_{tt}+4u_{ttxxxx}+u_{xx}=0$, And find the asymptotic behavior.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $u(t,x)$ be a bounded solution for the initial value problem $u_{tt}+4u_{ttxxxx}+u_{xx}=0$,
such that $u(0,x)=f(x) , u_{t}(0,x)=0$  such that $f(x) \in C^4(R)$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)|+|f'(x)|+|f''(x)|+|f'''(x)|+|f''''(x)|\, dx < \infty$

1.Find $u(t,x)$.

2.Find the asymptotic behavior of $u(t,x)$ such that $t\to\infty$

Attempted solution:

We find $u(t,x)$ by fourier transform $\widehat{u_{tt}}- \frac{k^2}{1+4k^4}\widehat{u}  = 0$

so $u(t,x) =\int_{-\infty}^\infty (A(k)e^{\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{1+4k^4}}t} +B(k)e^{-\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{1+4k^4}}t})e^{ikx} dk$

with the initial condition and the fact that $u(t,x)$ is a bounded solution
we get $u(t,x) =\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\widehat{f}(k)}{2}
e^{-\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{1+4k^4}}t} e^{ikx} dk$

2.Find the asymptotic behavior of $u(t,x)$ such that $t\to\infty$

The only method for this kind of problem is using the laplace method but

$-\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{1+4k^4}} \not\le \delta ln(|k|)$ for $M\le |k|$.

Comment: With two initial conditions, not sure you can cross out the term that’s growing exponentially in $t$?

Comment: Hi,  messenger. i  believe we can because $u(x,t)$ is the bounded solution.

Comment: You can have bounded as $t\to\infty$ or you can satisfy two initial conditions, you can’t have both. Are you sure bounded refers to its behaviour in $t$ or in $x$?

Comment: That a good question, I believe that bounded refers to its behaviour in t because t stands for time.

Comment: Hi, @ Gonçalo. 
yes it is a typo fixing it now.